# Invoke .exe file with keys, which was copied via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try execute .exe file which was copied from network folder to host folder with keys for silent installation by using this script:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\" -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
    Name = $_.FullName
}

} | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Invoke-Item -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"
```

But I receive error:

```
 Invoke-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name  's2'.
At line:20 char:78
+ ... ding | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Invoke-Item -s2 -sp"-Si ...
+                                                               ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Item], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeItemCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because you pass the parameters to the `Invoke-Item` cmdlet and not to your application,

Try to invoke your executeable with `&` and pass the parameters:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\" -Filter *.exe | Where Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | % {
New-Object psobject -Property @{
    No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
    Name = $_.FullName
}

} | Sort No -Descending | Select -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | 
 Foreach { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"}
```

Comment: Now I get this error:

The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.
At line:21 char:14
+  Foreach { & $_.FullName -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -Upda ...
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression

Comment: ah, you are creating a new object, so use `$_` instead, I update my answer

Comment: Martin it works! I don't know how to extend thanks. THANK YOU SO SO MUCH!